# Toggle <p:selectCheckboxMenu> items in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

How can I select or unselect items in `<p:selectCheckboxMenu>` component using JavaScript?

I have figured out only this way:

```
PF('selectCheckboxMenuWidgetVar').checkboxes[index_of_item].click();
```

But this generates "click" on element and invokes all handlers.
I want only (un)select item without invoking handlers.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer:

```
var widgetVar = PF('selectCheckboxMenuWidgetVar');
```

check:

```
widgetVar.check($(widgetVar.checkboxes[index_of_item]));
$(widgetVar.inputs[index_of_item]).prop('checked', true);
```

uncheck:

```
widgetVar.uncheck($(widgetVar.checkboxes[index_of_item]));
$(widgetVar.inputs[index_of_item]).prop('checked', false);
```

it is working for me.